# How to use React-Table without Node.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm new to React and I'm looking to use [react-table](https://react-table.tanstack.com/) in my Django app without Node.js.  I've embedded the react-table library in my app with a standard unpkg link but when I go to use its functions in `.js` files I get errors like `app.js:39 Uncaught ReferenceError: useTable is not defined`.  All of the tutorials import `useTable` through `import { useTable } from 'react-table'` but this is not possible when you are just trying to implement this cleint-side in the browser.  How would I use react-table without Node.js and its `import` functions?

Comment: This example uses React with react-table.  https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/basic?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @SanishJoseph Yes, but that example uses Node.js and `import` functions.  I'm trying to use React Table without Node.js but I do not know how to access any of its methods without Node.

Comment: Which functions are you talking about? If it's `const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data,
  })` They are not coming from Nodejs.

Comment: Are you trying to say you want to use react-table without react?

Comment: No, I have React and React-table embedded as unpkg script links in my HTML file.  However, it fails to recognize the `useTable` function in React-table.  I currently believe that its because I'm not using the `import` function I described above.

Answer (score 0):

You could you npm packages as script tags using unpkg.

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/browse/react-table@latest/react-table.min.js" />`

Source react table docs https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/installation

Comment: I have done that, however my JS files fail to recognize the React Table functions.  Their `<script>` links are placed after I load React Table so it is not an ordering issue I believe.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.